# Merge two pattern into one

Tags: java, regex

I need write a pattern to remove currency symbol and comma. eg `Fr.-145,000.01`
After the pattern matcher should return `-145000.01`.

The pattern i am using:

```
^[^0-9\\-]*([0-9\\-\\.\\,]*?)[^0-9\\-]*$
```

This will return `-145,000.01`

Then I remove the comma to get `-145000.01`, I want to ask if that's possible that I change the pattern and directly get `-145000.01`

```
String pattern = "^[^0-9\\-]*([0-9\\-\\.\\,]*?)[^0-9\\-]*$";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if(m.matches()) {
 System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

I expect the output could resolve the comma

Comment: Consider using `replaceAll`.

Comment: replaceAll actually works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply it with `String.replaceAll()` and simpler regex (providing you are expecting the input to be reasonably sane, i.e. without multiple decimal points embedded in the numbers or multiple negative signs)

```
   String str = "Fr.-145,000.01";
   str.replaceAll("[^\\d-.]\\.?", "")
```

If you are going down this route, I would sanity check it by parsing the output with `BigDecimal` or `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to just collect our desired digits, `.`, `+` and `-` in a capturing group followed by an optional comma, and then join them:

```
([+-]?[0-9][0-9.]+),?
```

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "([+-]?[0-9][0-9.]+),?";
final String string = "Fr.-145,000.01\n"
     + "Fr.-145,000\n"
     + "Fr.-145,000,000\n"
     + "Fr.-145\n"
     + "Fr.+145,000.01\n"
     + "Fr.+145,000\n"
     + "Fr.145,000,000\n"
     + "Fr.145\n"
     + "Fr.145,000,000,000.01";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RPva66/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "Fr.-145,000.01";

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^[^0-9-]*(-?[0-9]+)(?:,([0-9]{3}))?(?:,([0-9]{3}))?(?:,([0-9]{3}))?(\\.[0-9]+)?[^0-9-]*$");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(str);
System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("$1$2$3$4$5"));
```

Output:

```
-145000.01
```

It looks for number with up to 3 commas (Up to 999,999,999,999.99), and replaces it with the digits.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to remove all the unnecessary parts using `replaceAll`.

The unnecessary parts are, apparently:

1. Any sequence which is not digits or minus at the beginning of the string.
2. Commas

The first pattern is represented by `^[^\\d-]+`. The second is merely `,`.

Put them together with an `|`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^[^\\d-]+)|,");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
String result = m.replaceAll("");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could 2 capturing groups and make use of repeating matching using the `\G` anchor to assert the position at the end of the previous match.

```
(?:^[^0-9+-]+(?=[.+,\d-]*\.\d+$)([+-]?\d{1,3})|\G(?!^)),(\d{3})
```

In Java

```
String regex = "(?:^[^0-9+-]+(?=[.+,\\d-]*\\.\\d+$)([+-]?\\d{1,3})|\\G(?!^)),(\\d{3})";
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group
- `^[^0-9+-]+` Match 1+ times not a digit, `+` or `-`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert that what follows is:

  - `[.+,\d-]*\.\d+$` Match 0+ times what is allowed and assert ending on `.` and 1+ digits
- `)` Close positive lookahead
- `(` Capturing group 1

  - `[+-]?\d{1,3})` Match optional `+` or `-` followed by 1-3 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of prevous match, not at the start
- `),` Close capturing group 1 and match `,`
- `(\d{3})` Capture in group 2 matching 3 digits

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups `$1$2`

See the [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QT4Amn/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/lRqk5D)